# Liquibase lock - reasons?

Tags: database, oracle, liquibase

I get this when running a lot of liquibase-scripts against a Oracle-server. SomeComputer is me.

```
Waiting for changelog lock....
Waiting for changelog lock....
Waiting for changelog lock....
Waiting for changelog lock....
Waiting for changelog lock....
Waiting for changelog lock....
Waiting for changelog lock....
Liquibase Update Failed: Could not acquire change log lock.  Currently locked by SomeComputer (192.168.15.X) since 2013-03-20 13:39
SEVERE 2013-03-20 16:59:liquibase: Could not acquire change log lock.  Currently locked by SomeComputer (192.168.15.X) since 2013-03-20 13:39
liquibase.exception.LockException: Could not acquire change log lock.  Currently locked by SomeComputer (192.168.15.X) since 2013-03-20 13:39
        at liquibase.lockservice.LockService.waitForLock(LockService.java:81)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.tag(Liquibase.java:507)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:643)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:116)
```

Could it be that the number of simultaneous sessions/transactions are reached? Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Did you kill the JVM while liquibase held the lock? That's the only case where this occurs for me.

Comment: There seems to be another PC involved: Konsultpc74. Maybe you ran liquibase from to different PCs at the same time? If not do you have an explanation for the other PC?

Comment: I edited the logs and I accidently forgot to change that to SomeComputer

Comment: Are you executing the changesets simultaneously? I thought each file and each changeset in it is executed one by one. At least I use it this way. I have one master changeset file which inlcudes all others and everthing is run one by one.

Answer (score 891, accepted):

Sometimes if the update application is abruptly stopped, then the lock remains stuck.

Then running

```sql
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED=0, LOCKGRANTED=null, LOCKEDBY=null where ID=1;
```

against the database helps.

You may also need to replace `LOCKED=0` with `LOCKED=FALSE`.

Or you can simply drop the `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` table, it will be recreated.

Comment: I needed to switch out the `0` for `FALSE`, but other than that, it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: There is a built-in command in Liquibase called releaseLocks that would execute what @Adrian Ber answered but I think it is database agnostic.

Comment: I was just getting this error in my development environment. Fixing up the DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table solved it.

Comment: I needed to switch out the `FALSE` for `b'0'`

Comment: This is the correct solution, don't try emptying the table as that won't help. Either DROP it or UPDATE the LOCKED flag to 'FALSE'

Comment: No False in SQL Server if that is what you are using
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED=0, LOCKGRANTED=null, LOCKEDBY=null where ID=1;

Comment: This seems like a SQL injection

Comment: Why SQL injection?

Comment: the [logs](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/databasechangeloglock-table.html)

Comment: Finally this helped me, thanks. My issue was I had multiple schemas in MySQL Workbench and occasionally looked at the wrong one. Once I figured out the correct scheme, I was able to figure out the lock is indeed acquired, and reset it using `false` instead of `0` as mentioned several times above.

Comment: Works event when upon select it looks good. Meaning locked is false. It is locked on DB level.

Comment: In my case, instead of droping the table deleted the current causing record. hence it is working . thanks

Answer (score 82):

### Edit june 2020

Don't follow this advice. It's caused trouble to many people over the years. It worked for me a long time ago and I posted it in good faith, but it's clearly not the way to do it. The DATABASECHANGELOCK table needs to have stuff in it, so it's a bad idea to just delete everything from it without dropping the table.

[Leos Literak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528795/liquibase-lock-reasons/30393219?noredirect=1#comment110444052_30393219), for instance, followed these instructions and the server failed to start.

### Original answer

It's possibly due to a killed liquibase process not releasing its lock on the DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table. Then,

```
DELETE FROM DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK;
```

might help you.

**Edit:** @Adrian Ber's answer provides a better solution than this. Only do this if you have any problems doing his solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Rachcha I explained it better. Hope you like it more like this.

Comment: Do not follow the advice above. DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK  must contain rows without any rows you will get an exception

Comment: This does not help, I tried this rather than dropping the table or update locked state to 'false'.
It didn't worked.

Comment: If you follow this answer there is a good chance future scripts will not run because they expect the lock to exist. If you have done this already you can add an empty lock to fix the issue  

`INSERT INTO yourdb.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK VALUES (1, 0, null, null);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119115/liquibase-update-error/26870086

Comment: I made a mistake and followed these instructions and the server failed to start. I fixed it with: insert into DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK values(1,false,null,null);

Comment: @LeosLiterak I'm sorry my answer caused you trouble. Over the years it seems to have caused more harm than good. I'm gonna edit it to reflect that. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Deleting the row is bad, but dropping the entire table should work. Liquibase just doesn't like an empty table

Answer (score 28):

The problem was the buggy implementation of SequenceExists in Liquibase. Since the changesets with these statements took a very long time and was accidently aborted. Then the next try executing the liquibase-scripts the lock was held.

```
  <changeSet author="user" id="123">
    <preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
      <not><sequenceExists sequenceName="SEQUENCE_NAME_SEQ" /></not>
    </preConditions>
    <createSequence sequenceName="SEQUENCE_NAME_SEQ"/>
  </changeSet>
```

A work around is using plain SQL to check this instead:

```
  <changeSet author="user" id="123">
    <preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
            <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">
              select count(*) from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'SEQUENCE_NAME_SEQ';
            </sqlCheck>
    </preConditions>
    <createSequence sequenceName="SEQUENCE_NAME_SEQ"/>
  </changeSet>
```

Lockdata is stored in the table DATABASECHANGELOCK. To get rid of the lock you just change 1 to 0 or drop that table and recreate.

Comment: In liquibase 3.0.2 (the version I am using), do not remove the one line from the lock table, or you will have a different error when running liquibase the next time, because liquibase expects that one row to be there (or the whole table missing).

Exactly as Peter said, just wanted to add that info, because in older versions it seems to have worked to also remove the row.

Answer (score 16):

It is not mentioned which environment is used for executing Liquibase. In case it is Spring Boot 2 it is possible to extend `liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService` without the need to run direct SQL statements which is much cleaner. E.g.:

```
/**
 * This class is enforcing to release the lock from the database.
 *
 */
 public class ForceReleaseLockService extends StandardLockService {

    @Override
    public int getPriority() {
        return super.getPriority()+1;
    }

    @Override
    public void waitForLock() throws LockException {
        try {
            super.forceReleaseLock();
        } catch (DatabaseException e) {
            throw new LockException("Could not enforce getting the lock.", e);
        }
        super.waitForLock();
    }
}
```

The code is enforcing the release of the lock. This can be useful in test setups where the release call might not get called in case of errors or when the debugging is aborted.

The class must be placed in the `liquibase.ext` package and will be picked up by the Spring Boot 2 auto configuration.

### Liquibase 4

Note that the extension loading mechanism has changed in [Liquibase 4](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/extensions/extension-upgrade-guides/lb-4.0-upgrade-guide.html?Highlight=extension).

Now a file under `META-INF/services` with the implemented full interface package name must be created and in this file all extension must be listed.

This could mean that in `META-INF/services/liquibase.lockservice.LockService`

This line must be added:

```
com.company.liquibase.impl.ForceReleaseLockService
```

I have not tried it, still using Liquibase 3, please edit and correct.

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed description of your solution? We use Spring Boot 2 and liquibase and do not want to delete the lock-state in the db each time manually. But I did not understand how do you inject the ForceReleaseLockService to the liquibase. Don`t I have to put a Service/Component annotation over this class, that Spring choose it as a primary bean?

Comment: It is mentioned in the last sentence: "The class must be placed in the liquibase.ext package and will be picked up by the Spring Boot 2 auto configuration."

Comment: How do you place the class in `liquibase.ext`, do I need to define that package in my  project?

Comment: I defined that package in my project, it seems to work but I can't verify it. I defined a `@PostConstruct` method with a log message but I don't see it printed.

Comment: @akuma8: Yes, just create a package in your project with that name. Where did you define the `@PostConstruct` method? In the ForceReleaseLockService? This is not a Spring service, so this will not get invoked.

Comment: Yes in the ForceReleaseLockService. Do you think that we can use a such hack in production with microservices architecture? If we have multiple instances, one instance could force the first one getting the lock to free it even it has not finished DB update.

Comment: I'm only using this for unit tests and not in the production code. In a production environment I would not expect to see this often, only in cases when the container is not starting up correctly, but this is usually already detected for the most time in a staging environment. In a production environment if this happens unlock the table manually.

Comment: @к_о_: I put the specified class in the liquibase.ext package in the root of the test loop project. but it doesn't work. How should SpringBoot know about this ?

Comment: @skyho: Spring boot is by default checking this package. I don't know what a test loop project is. Maybe here the test loop project is referencing to a test execution? I have never tried to just use this during a test, but actually the classpath should still pick it up.

Comment: @к_о_:  and yet it is not clear how to use it. I created a package and put it there. I don't see the SpringBootTest context seeing this class. How to do everything right. someone please post an example. I put the class in the root : test/java/my_root_test_contour/liquibase/ext

Comment: `test/java/my_root_test_contour/liquibase/ext` is a standard path of you build tool? Maven and Gradle are using `src/test/java/...`

Comment: This never worked for me.

Comment: @Chizl: Is liquibase otherwise working your Spring boot project? You might have to migrate my advice to version 4 maybe? I will add some links to my original answer: https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/extensions/extension-upgrade-guides/lb-4.0-upgrade-guide.html?Highlight=extension

Comment: Ill check the version at work.  Unfortunately I work for a very large company that has their own repos for these.  Ill check to see if we have the latest at least from our repo.

Answer (score 12):

You can safely delete the table manually or using query. It will be recreated automatically.

```
DROP TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK;
```

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate this wasn't the OP's issue, but I ran into this issue recently with a different cause. For reference, I was using the Liquibase Maven plugin (liquibase-maven-plugin:3.1.1) with SQL Server.

Anyway, I'd erroneously copied and pasted a SQL Server "use" statement into one of my scripts that switches databases, so liquibase was running and updating the `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK`, acquiring the lock in the correct database, but then switching databases to apply the changes. Not only could I NOT see my changes or liquibase audit in the correct database, but of course, when I ran liquibase again, it couldn't acquire the lock, as the lock had been released in the "wrong" database, and so was still locked in the "correct" database. I'd have expected liquibase to check the lock was still applied before releasing it, and maybe that is a bug in liquibase (I haven't checked yet), but it may well be addressed in later versions! That said, I suppose it could be considered a feature!

Quite a bit of a schoolboy error, I know, but I raise it here in case anyone runs into the same problem!

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes truncating or dropping the table DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK doesn't work. I use PostgreSQL database and came across this issue a lot of times. What I do for solving is to rollback the prepared statements running in background for that database. Try to rollback all the prepared statements and try the liquibase changes again.

SQL:

```
SELECT gid FROM pg_prepared_xacts WHERE database='database_name';
```

If above statement returns any record, then rollback that prepared statement with following SQL statement.

```
ROLLBACK PREPARED 'gid_obtained_from_above_SQL';
```

Answer (score 3):

Please let Liquibase handle its own tables. The correct thing to do, as user1434769 mentions, is to use Liquibase's releaseLocks command.

When using Gradle, this would be: `gradlew releaseLocks`

Answer (score 2):

I have previously just truncated the DatabaseChangeLogLock table when a lock remained after failure (and this generally still works for me).

However, this project (https://github.com/blagerweij/liquibase-sessionlock) now exists, which uses native database session locks for locking Liquibase when using Oracle, PostgreSQL and MySQL.

The JAR file can be dropped into an existing Liquibase 4.x+ application, and will be automatically detected by Liquibase. This will use session locks for locking.. which are automatically released if the application crashes or is shutdown whilst the lock is held. This will potentially stop the locked state from occuring (if you are using one of the supported databases)

Answer (score 1):

In **postgres 12** I needed to use this command:

```
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED=false, LOCKGRANTED=null, LOCKEDBY=null where ID=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Default table for liquibase changelog is DATABASECHANGELOCK, however this can be overriden or set to a custom table by setting the below property.

in application.properties

```
database-change-log-lock-table=<SOME_CUSTOM_TABLE_NAME>
```

If the application has this property set then

```
UPDATE <SOME_CUSTOM_TABLE_NAME> SET LOCKED=0, LOCKGRANTED=null, LOCKEDBY=null where ID=1;
```

or delete the table

```
drop table <SOME_CUSTOM_TABLE_NAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the solution posted by @Adrian didn't work, you may try to do the same in the table INTERFACE_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK which contains additional informations regarding the lock.

```
UPDATE INTERFACE_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED=0, LOCKGRANTED=null, LOCKEDBY=null where ID=1;
```

or simply clear the table

```
TRUNCATE TABLE INTERFACE_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
```