# Liquibase Snapshot fails with Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, liquibase

I m pretty new to liquibase. But here is what I m doing:

```
liquibase --username=XXX --password='XXX' --driver=net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver --url='jdbc:snowflake://lala.east-us-2lala.azure.snowflakecomputing.com?db=dbname&schema=schemaname&warehouse=warehousename'  --snapshotFormat=json snapshot --output-file=snapshot.json
```

And here are the drivers and their versions:

```
Liquibase Version: 4.4.3
Liquibase Community 4.4.3 by Datical
```

`liquibase-snowflake-4.4.3.jar`

`snowflake-jdbc-3.13.7.jar`

And after running for a while it just keeps on failing with:

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: Expected single row from liquibase.statement.core.GetViewDefinitionStatement@e04ccf8 but got 0

Can anyone help with some guidance regarding the probable causes? If i run it with debug level log it does show that its fetching few tables and procedures but fails somewhere in between.

Comment: This looks incorrect : lala.east-us-2lala.azure or is it a typo while copying the account id for snowflake?

Comment: Not an error. The url has been modified obviously to mask the actual domain/url.

Comment: Looks to be similar to the issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119115/liquibase-update-error

Comment: I run into this issue as soon as there is a **materialized view** in the schema.