# liquibase Lock Exception even when DB unlocked

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat7, liquibase

I have my application deployed on tomcat7. It connects to the MySql DataBase in the backend.
Where I have the DATABASECHANGELOG, its LOCK and User tables configured in the 'core' schema.
When starting the tomcat server, I am facing the below issue.

**INFO 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock

INFO 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: Reading from `partner`.`DATABASECHANGELOG`

INFO 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: Reading from `partner`.`DATABASECHANGELOG`

WARNING 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: modifyDataType will lose primary key/autoincrement/not null settings for mysql.  Use  and re-specify all configuration if this is the case

INFO 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock

INFO 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock

INFO 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: Reading from `core`.`DATABASECHANGELOG`

INFO 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: Reading from `core`.`DATABASECHANGELOG`

WARNING 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: modifyDataType will lose primary key/autoincrement/not null settings for mysql.  Use  and re-specify all configuration if this is the case

WARNING 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: modifyDataType will lose primary key/autoincrement/not null settings for mysql.  Use  and re-specify all configuration if this is the case

WARNING 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: modifyDataType will lose primary key/autoincrement/not  null settings for mysql.  Use  and re-specify all configuration if this is the case

WARNING 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: modifyDataType will lose primary key/autoincrement/not null settings for mysql.  Use  and re-specify all configuration if this is the case

WARNING 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: modifyDataType will lose primary key/autoincrement/not null settings for mysql.  Use  and re-specify all configuration if this is the case

WARNING 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: modifyDataType will lose primary key/autoincrement/not null settings for mysql.  Use  and re-specify all configuration if this is the case

INFO 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock

INFO 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock

INFO 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: Reading from `partner`.`DATABASECHANGELOG`

INFO 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: Reading from `partner`.`DATABASECHANGELOG`

WARNING 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: modifyDataType will lose primary key/autoincrement/not null settings for mysql.  Use  and re-specify all configuration if this is the case

INFO 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock

...

14/09/07 11:04:49 INFO support.GenericXmlApplicationContext: Refreshing   org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext@771b9e: startup date [Sun Sep 07 11:04:49 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy

14/09/07 11:04:49 INFO support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer: Loading properties file from class path resource [jdbc.properties]

14/09/07 11:04:49 INFO support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@587dcb: defining beans [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0,entityManagerFactory,taxonomy.transaction.manager,taxonomy.datasource,taxonomy.liquibase]; root of factory hierarchy

14/09/07 11:04:49 INFO jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'inference.taxonomy'

14/09/07 11:04:49 INFO ejb.Ejb3Configuration: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: inference.taxonomy

    ...]

14/09/07 11:04:49 INFO internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider:  org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider

14/09/07 11:04:49 INFO dialect.Dialect: HHH000400: Using dialect:   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

14/09/07 11:04:50 INFO internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory

14/09/07 11:04:50 INFO ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

INFO 7/9/14 11:04 AM:liquibase: Waiting for changelog lock....

INFO 7/9/14 11:05 AM:liquibase: Waiting for changelog lock....

INFO 7/9/14 11:05 AM:liquibase: Waiting for changelog lock....

INFO 7/9/14 11:05 AM:liquibase: Waiting for changelog lock....

INFO 7/9/14 11:05 AM:liquibase: Waiting for changelog lock....

INFO 7/9/14 11:05 AM:liquibase: Waiting for changelog lock....

INFO 7/9/14 11:05 AM:liquibase: Waiting for changelog lock....

INFO 7/9/14 11:06 AM:liquibase: Waiting for changelog lock....

....

Caused by: liquibase.exception.LockException: Could not acquire change log lock.  Currently locked by 10.1.202.X (10.1.202.X) since 5/9/14 11:23 PM

    at liquibase.lockservice.LockService.waitForLock(LockService.java:81)

    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:102)

    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:262)

    atliquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:245)**

At the DB level the DataBaseChangeLogLock table has locked field unlocked as shown below

**ID , Locked, LockGranted, LockedBy**

'1', '0',      NULL,        NULL

Even when why I remove all the DATABASECHANGELOG related tables before starting my server I am facing the same issue.

I don't find any resoution for this issue in
[Liquibase lock - reasons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528795/liquibase-lock-reasons)

Comment: I think your application opens connection to the database after a startup, or maybe you forgot to close any opened by it JDBC connections. So Liquibase actually can't acquire lock, because it is acquired by your web-appication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was resolved. The DATABASECHANGELOG table I was looking was in another schema "core.DATABASECHANGELOG", where as the lock acquired was in "platform.DATABASECHANGELOG".

Once I updated the correct Log table it was resolved.