# Can no longer deploy Grails 2.2.5 app on Tomcat

Tags: grails

I have run into a very serious problem where I can longer deploy a war of a Grails 2.2.5 web application on Tomcat. The build (with 'grails war') proceeds without a problem, and I deploy it to Tomcat. I retsart Tomcat, and the web application simply does not run. It comes up with the deploying message, but clearly doesn't get as far as running Bootstrap.groovy, because logging from there doesn't show up in the log. No error messages are given, but the web app is simply not running.

I ran into a similar problem a few days ago on a different server which I solved by upgrading to Tomcat 7, but this one is already running Tomcat 7. I have no idea why this has started happening, unless it is something obscure to do with the recent change in Maven where only TLS 1.2 connections are allowed (a change which occurred a week or so ago).

So what could be happening? Is there some way I can log what is happening as the web app starts up, such that I might be able to see where the problem is occurring?

If it is of any relevance, it works OK when I do 'grails run-war' on my development machine.

Comment: Deadlock from db-migration?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528795/liquibase-lock-reasons

Comment: Change the log level: https://dzone.com/articles/grails-goodness-set-log-level and paste the output